# Can't insert Image byte array into SQLite Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm trying to get image from gallery and convert it into Bitmap first from URI then converting it into byte array and then trying to store it into database of BLOB datatype column. Insert query returns successful message but not reflecting into the database. But when I pass empty byte array into it then it stores the entire row.

Code of Bitmap to byte[] :

```
byte[] imgByteArray;

        int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
        imgByteArray = byteBuffer.array();
```

**UPDATE :**

**CODE TO GET IMAGE FROM GALLERY & BYTE CONVERTION & STORE INTO DB :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_PICTURE);


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            

            if (requestCode == PICK_PICTURE) {
                if (data.getData() != null) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();

                    try {
                        pictureBitmap = getBitmapFromUri(uri);

            byte[] imgByteArray;

                int size = pictureBitmap.getRowBytes() * pictureBitmap.getHeight();
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
                pictureBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
                imgByteArray = byteBuffer.array();

            


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
    }
   }
}

    public boolean insertPicture(byte[] picture, String desc){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();

        cValues.put(KEY_PICTURE, picture);
        cValues.put(KEY_DESC, desc);
        
        long rowId = db.insert(PICTURE_TABLE,null, cValues);
        Log.d("TAG","Row ID : "+rowId);

        db.close();
        if(rowId!=0){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: please provide code you use to get image from gallery, to store this image to database and to retreive it from database

Comment: I have Updated the question with code. Please take a look. thanks

Comment: `trying to get image from gallery and convert it into Bitmap first ` That looks like a bad idea. Especially because you wanna put all its pixels in an array before saving. That will cost you a lot of storage space. Probably more then twenty times as much compared to when you just stored the selected jpg file.

Comment: @blackapps Ohhh i didn't know this. So from your point of you for better memory management what's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: That i already told you: store -the bytes of- the selected jpg file itself. Dont use an intermediate bitmap.

Comment: @blackapps You mean to say like this :

  Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        mImageByteArray = data.getExtras().getByteArray(ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_IMAGE);

Comment: I have never used that statement. Dont know. But think that it will not work. At the moment you try to fill a byte array and then put that byte array in the database. What i said was that you are filling that byte array in the wrong way by using an intermediate bitmap. Instead you should just fill your byte array with the bytes of the file.

Comment: @blackapps to be honest, I am not getting what you are trying to say and want me to do. Can you please tell me?

Comment: Implement the suggestions of Alex Rmcf. Then have a good sleep. After that you will see the light.

Answer (score 1):

In onActivityResult method:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
InputStream inStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outStream);       
byte[] imgBytes = outStream.toByteArray();
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String sql = "INSERT INTO YOURTABLENAME (id,image) VALUES(?,?)";
SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);
statement.clearBindings();
statement.bindString(1, Integer.toString(someId));
statement.bindBlob(2, imgBytes);
statement.executeInsert();
db.close();
```

i reccomend you to store your image bytes with id to easy retrieve it then

Comment: You are converting a jpg image file to a png image. Png's take more memory. Usually one would like to use as little memory as possible.

Comment: you are right, but i think question was about how to do that, not how to do that best way)

Comment: @alex-rmcf so you mean, I have to set images this way? Can't use the method I'm using right now? I mean db.INSERT method?

Comment: So if i want to use this way :


        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();

        cValues.put(KEY_PICTURE, picture);
        cValues.put(KEY_DESC, desc);
        
        long rowId = db.insert(PICTURE_TABLE,null, cValues);
        Log.d("TAG","Row ID : "+rowId);

        db.close();
        if(rowId!=0){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
I cant use it?

Comment: of course you can, i just shared some working method from my current project

Comment: and according to perfomance - using statement is faster then content values.

Comment: Ohhh that's a new knowledge i got today. Thank you so much Alex :)

Comment: @AlexRmcf I've tried with your way of converting image into byte array, and it's converting it. But using ContentValues still i am not able to insert it into the table. Why?

Comment: did you create table right way? with id text and image blob columns?